# Update stored procedure not updating one of the columns

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, query-string

If I execute the stored procedure in SQL Server everything works as expected, however when I get web forms to do it problems arise.

Everything seems to be updating fine except the column `Estado`, the parameter `Estado` (means `Status` in Portuguese) is obtained by checking whether or not checkbox1 is checked, if it is then the variable `Estado` will be set to `Completado` (completed) and to `Pendente` (`pending`) if not.

I then assign the value of the parameter `@Estado` the value of the variable `Estado`.

Below you can see the code that is inside of `Button_Click` and the stored procedure.

```
 Dim ConnStr As String = "Data Source=MARTIM-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=EnotelSuporte;Integrated Security=True"
    Dim SqlCommand As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    SqlCommand.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
    SqlCommand.CommandText = "Pedido_Update"
    SqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@PedidoId", Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = PedidoID
    SqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Resolucao", Data.SqlDbType.NText).Value = TextBox3.Text
    SqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Observacoes", Data.SqlDbType.NText).Value = TextBox2.Text

    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        Estado = "Completado"
    ElseIf CheckBox1.Checked = False Then
        Estado = "Pendente"
    End If

    SqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Estado", Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Estado
    SqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@IdDepartamento", Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue
    SqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@IdTipoGeral", Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = DropDownList2.SelectedValue
    SqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@IdTipoEspecifico", Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = DropDownList3.SelectedValue
    SqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@IdHotel", Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = DropDownList4.SelectedValue
    SqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Descricao", Data.SqlDbType.NText).Value = TextBox1.Text

    Dim SqlConnection As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConnStr)
    SqlCommand.Connection = SqlConnection

    SqlConnection.Open()
    SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    SqlConnection.Close()
```

Edited code to use local variable as suggested (still doesn't work):

```
 Dim Estado2 As String = "Pendente"
    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        Estado2 = "Completado"
    End If
    SqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Estado", Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =    Estado2
```

I also tried this in order to remove the need for variables (which also doesn't work, starting to think the problem's with the use of the CheckBox1):

```
    If CheckBox1.Checked Then
        SqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Estado", Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "Completado"
    ElseIf CheckBox1.Checked = False Then
        SqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Estado", Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "Pendente"
    End If
```

This is the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Pedido_Update]  
    @PedidoId int,
    @Observacoes ntext,
    @IdDepartamento int,
    @IdHotel int,
    @IdTipoEspecifico int,
    @IdTipoGeral int,
    @Resolucao ntext,
    @Descricao ntext,
    @Estado nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    UPDATE Pedidos 
    SET Resolucao = @Resolucao,
        Observacoes = @Observacoes,
        IdDepartamento = @IdDepartamento, 
        IdHotel = @IdHotel, 
        IdTipoEspecifico = @IdTipoEspecifico,
        IdTipoGeral = @IdTipoGeral,
        PedidoDescricao = @Descricao,
        Estado = @Estado
    WHERE 
        IdPedido = @PedidoId
END
```

Just noticed something interesting. The value of `CheckBox1.Checked` is `True` when there are no QueryStrings in the URL (example :  `http://localhost:50851/Gestor/Pedidos/PedidoVisualizar.aspx`). When there are QueryStrings (Example: `http://localhost:50851/Gestor/Pedidos/PedidoVisualizar.aspx?PedidoId=4`) `CheckBox1.Checked` is set to `False` independently of having checked it or not.

Comment: Where is the variable `Estado` declared in your ASP.NET code?

Comment: It's a global variable, outside of any methods.

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant to your problem but you declare the parameter @pedidoid of type nvarchar but it is expected to be an integer

Comment: does this work `SqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Estado", Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "Some Value"` if it does the problem lies with `estado` variable (maybe make it local?) if not the problem is probably with your stored proc.

Comment: That works. I've changed my code a bit to use local variables, check the code. It still doesn't work though.

Comment: Can you try running sql profiler? This should allow you to verify that data that is getting sent to the server.

Comment: Well, I did as Dave Becker suggested and switched from using the variable "Estado" to just a regular string and the update worked fine. The problem seems to be with using variables to set the value of that parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code seems to be fine. But if I right understood you're using a "global" variable to store Estado, and it depends on a control in a webform, you should consider the possibility that this form in a different session might change the value in Estado before of after saving your data on SQL.

In other words, you can't trust the value you get is the value set by your webform as you are sharing this variable for all opened sessions.

If it's not that case may be you have to provide more information and some code from your asp.net application
Hope that help

Comment: I tried removing all use of variables with this code and it still didn't work. w`If CheckBox1.Checked Then
        SqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Estado", Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "Completado"
    ElseIf CheckBox1.Checked = False Then
        SqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Estado", Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "Pendente"
    End If`

Comment: Have you debugged it? I mean, can you see the value of CheckBox1 just before calling the SP?

Comment: Yeah, it's set to False even if I check it.

Comment: Just noticed something interesting. The value of `CheckBox1.Checked` is `True` when there are no QueryStrings in the URL (example :  `http://localhost:50851/Gestor/Pedidos/PedidoVisualizar.aspx`). When there are QueryStrings (Example: `http://localhost:50851/Gestor/Pedidos/PedidoVisualizar.aspx?PedidoId=4`) `CheckBox1.Checked` is set to `False` independently of having checked it or not.

Comment: Then it's possible you are binding the checkbox with previous data from DB before call the SP. Are you using Page.IsPostBack to check that? You should bind or set values to control when the Page/Usercontrol is loaded the first time. But not when you save it (Postback) because you'll overwrite form values with values from DB.

Comment: That fixed the problem, added `If Page.IsPostBack = False Then` `My Code` `End If` to the control and it's now working.